# Stuck at a step in reduction formula integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

[image]

I have to give to the reduction formula a relationship between $I_n$ and $I_{n-2}$ , I'm stuck in my last point where I have to integrate $\tan^{n-2} x \sec^2 x$ , how do we go about integrate that?

Comment: Your handwriting is not legible.  You need to type your computations.

Comment: Ok sorry, but I post pictures of my writing because when I used to type put the question people used to comment things like what have u done so far, can you share your working sort of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: substitute $u=\tan{x}$. Then,

$$\int\tan^a {x}\sec^2{x}\,dx=\int u^adu=\frac{1}{a+1}u^{a+1}+constant=\frac{1}{a+1}(\tan{x})^{a+1}+constant$$

Comment: Thank you a lot :) I understand now how to do